# Unity 5 scene bug with UI texts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having problem with UI Texts in Unity. So I have few UI texts in Scene. And problem appears when i just get out of Unity.. E.g I press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> or just from my toolbar open another application ( Google Chrome).. Then I'll return back to Unity and .. The texts disappear. But it´s only in Scene Editor.. I must remove Scene Editor and than add it back for see those texts.¨

Images can be helpful for understanding my problem

## This is image with texts:

[image: This is image with texts]

## This is image without texts:

[image: This is image without texts]

Comment: The latest one. I think it's 5.3.4p6 but i had 5.3.4f1 and there was same problem with texts.

Comment: Do what I said in my answer if that didn't work, let me know in the comment of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bug or a graphic card/driver problem. The only way to find out which one is the problem is if you upgrade to the [latest](http://unity3d.com/unity/beta) **version 5.4.0B17**.

Comment: Ok. It didn't work. In this version is still that same problem.

Comment: @CallMany You sure you downloaded  5.4.0B17?

Comment: Do you have any idea to fix this problem ?

Comment: I have few more ideas. When they disappear, Press Play and then Stop and let me know if the Texts are back.

Comment: Yeah. They are back. Or if I click on button called Gizmos. Or if the project is not saved and i press CTRL + S.

Comment: @CallMany So that's your temporary solution until unity fixes this. Press play and stop to bring them back.

Comment: So that´s Unity's fault. Not my fault. Right ?

Comment: But it's strange. Becouse my friend have same unity version but his Texts never disappear.

Comment: @CallMany Does he do what you are doing? Do what you are doing on your computer on your friends computer and see if the Text will disappear. If they do then it's Unity's fault. If they don't then it graphic problem. Let me know. Make sure to use the-same project.

Comment: Ok. I'll let you know tomorow. He's not online.

Comment: btw. Thank you for help ^^

Comment: @CallMany Ok Let me know. I want to hear what happens. The UI problem I have with Unity is when you move a UI Image somtimes, it disappears. Playing and Stopping it brings them back. I think this is a bug but we will find out tomorrow.

Comment: Hi. I have news. It's very strange, but when I have created new project, this problem has been solved. Texts didn't disappeared ^^